# Custom fields of type select not displaying in Activity Report

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, activities, 4.6

A site I'm working on has recently been upgraded to version 4.6.32.  Since this upgrade the client is no longer able to see data from some of the custom fields in the Activity Report.

Custom fields of type 'text' display fine, but fields of type 'select' are blank even though there is data stored in this field.

The site is running CiviCRM 4.6.32 on Drupal 7.

Comment: The patch noted below did not work for my issue. I'm still digging around to find the culprit, as mentioned it only check box, radio displays without issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update Keith. Let us know what you discover.

Comment: The patch didn't work for me. The if statement in the patch is never true because $value always contains a square character at either end. And they don't exist in $cf_values['value'] (at least not for my data).

Comment: Just updated to 4.6.36 and the bug has been resolved!  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in CiviCRM 4.6.32.  (It doesn't appear to affect CiviCRM 4.7.28.)

I have recreated this on the [sandbox site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/3?reset=1).

I have raised this as a bug in the CiviCRM issue queue:

[Custom fields of type select not displaying in Activity Report](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21333)

**UPDATE**

It was subsequently raised as a bug by Martin Castle:

[Custom data fails to pull through to reports](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21402)

And a fix has been released by VangelisP:

[Resolves regression issue with non-dynamic custom fields](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11262)

This will hopefully be included in a future release of CiviCRM 4.6

Comment: I see the same issue after upgrading Drupal installation to 4.6.32, just installed 4.6.33 and the issue remains. I have two custom fields in the same report, the radio type appears normally but the check box type does not show the field value that is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Just updated to 4.6.36 and the bug has been resolved! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `in_selector` column in the `civicrm_custom_field` table? I seem to recollect I had to set those to 1 but I am not sure...

Comment: Thanks Eric, I don't actually have access to the database for this site but I've managed to recreate the issue on the sandbox site so I don't think it is about any specific database settings.